# Updating data of selected row in datagridview

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, datagridview

I have datagridview with checkbox column and I want to update one value on a button click.Pending status=0 and Approved status=1. If I code

```
UPDATE pending SET status='1' WHERE status='0'
```

All status='0' will be '1' even the row without check. I want to update status to 1 only to the selected rows.  My codes are as follows:

```
private void btnApproved_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        List<DataGridViewRow> selectedRows = (from row in gvPending.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>() where Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells["checkBoxColumn"].Value) == true select row).ToList();
        if (MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Do you want to approve these rows?"), "Confirmation", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in selectedRows)
            {
                using (var connect = sqlcon.getConnection())
                {
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE pending SET status='1' WHERE /* checkboxColumnValue is true */  "))
                    {
                        cmd.Connection = connect;
                        connect.Open();
                        //cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        //connect.Close();

                    }
                }
            }
            this.BindGrid();
            //this.BindGrid1();
            //this.BindGrid2();
        }
    }
```

Any suggestions or corrections? Thanks!

Comment: Although the selected answer provides a good enough solution, there are various issues which you should take care of. When dealing with SQL queries, you should always rely on parametrisation rather than on plain strings (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy6y35y8(v=vs.110).aspx). Other issue in your code is that it connects as many times as elements in the given collection what is a quite inefficient proceeding; you should better build the query within the loop (e.g., a string variable starting with "UPDATE pending SET..." and adding all the ID=val linked with OR) and connect afterwards

Comment: Finally, note that building the initial `selectedRows` collection is not strictly required (= unnecessary waste of time and memory resources), unless wanting the user intervention. That is: if you need to check whether there are cases meeting your conditions before going to the main loop, it would be fine (i.e., another query like `FirstOrDefault` or even `Count` would be quicker, but not much quicker). In any other case (i.e., performing the analysis right away), you should avoid the initial query and loop through all the rows directly (by checking `row.Cells["checkBoxColumn"].Value`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your database primary key is named ID and that it is at position 0 of your grid then you should be able to use the ID in your command to modify only that record.

```
using (var connect = sqlcon.getConnection())
{
    string updateRecordCmd = String.Format( "UPDATE pending SET status='1' WHERE ID={0}",row.Cells[0].Value.toString());  
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(updateRecordCmd))
    {
        cmd.Connection = connect;
        connect.Open();
        //cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        //connect.Close();

    }
}
```

Good Luck!

Comment: @PaulEmmanuelAustria Although this answer is essentially answering your question, it is quite incomplete and doesn't mention various issues in your code. Take a look at my comments above for more information.